# Differences between webservice and web-application internal implementation

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

I have written some simple web-application using plain Servlets and simple RESTful web-service using JAx-RS.

I did read the difference between a web-application and web-service (web-app mainly for human consumption whereas web-services for computer / program consumption).

I have difficulty in understanding what exactly is the difference in internal implementation. Does both use Servlets (at least if talking about RESTful ws)? What exact is difference between in the way (of technology / software framework) they are implemented.

For example, I used tomcat as container for both Web-Service and Web-application (using servlets), what exactly is the difference.

Any answers highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I would say that web-services are a subset of web-aplications (an application, that is made for usage through the web). One application could even serve both, humans and computers. The difference is not in the implementation, its in the way information is provided. For humans, html is a good way to present the data. For computers, xml and json are a better way. Many websites offer an api, which can be used from machines and a website which can be used by humans. The way it is implemented internally does not matter here.

Comment: @ErikP: Thanks so much for your insight on this. Helpful indeed.